# Is it okay to use .write rules in .validate situations inside firebase 3.x rules?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I work with Firebase 3.x rules/security and am still trying to figure out the best way to setup my system.

I understand how I should use the .read, .write, and .validate functions, but I stumbled over a simple solution in some cases and wonder if this is okay for me to use. Let's say I would have normally a rule like this:

```
".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() === 'user_is_admin'",
```

which allows any user to **write if the user is an admin**.
Now if I have another object where I allow everybody to write, but don't want one specific field to be touched by users other than the admin, I use this:

```
".write": "auth != null",
   "option1": { ".validate": true },
   "option2": { ".validate": true },
   "option3": { ".validate": true }, 
   "option4": { ".validate": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() === 'user_is_admin'" }
```

Which allows any authenticated user to write (any field basically) in this case options 1, 2, 3, and 4, but since option4 only validates if the user is an admin (copy from the rule before), no normal user could touch this single parameter.

It works perfectly fine, but I wonder if it is okay to work like this. I think this makes it much easier in many cases instead of writing my own .read and .write rules for each sub item, which normally would be the case, since I actually give with my first .write full access and can't--later, inside any option--take it away again from the user. (except with my version)

Comment: Validation rules are not executed when data is deleted. So with your rules any authenticated used could still delete the data.

Comment: This is an important information, thx for that, I did not think about this and thats why I asked here. How ever this means I can still use in certain cases when delete is not an issue and I only want to prevent that a common user override data. Like for example permissions for a user. I do not have a problem if the user DELETE all his permissions but he cant set/override with my solution unless he is an admin.